# Numbering table columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns:

1. Country
2. OrderView

`Country` column is already filled. So I need to fill `OrderView` column in the following way:

```
Country        OrderView
------------------------
United States     1
Afghanistan       2
Aland Islands     3
Albania           4
```

And so on by alphabetical order (United States must be first).

I know how to do it in linq2sql but I have trouble with SQL. Can you help me?

Comment: Could you please add to tags database and version you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the questions is for SQL Server you can use a `case` and `row_number`.

```
update C
set OrderView = case
                  when Country = 'United States' then 1
                  when Country > 'United States' then rn
                  else rn + 1
                end
from (
      select OrderView,
             Country,
             row_number() over(order by Country) rn
      from YourTable
     ) as C
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/77223)

Comment: Hi .Mikael do you know any good guide / tutorial for sql server indexes ?

Comment: Have look at SQL Server Central [Stairway to Indexes](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/). Haven't read it myself yet but it is on my todo list.